# Azure App Gateway V2 cannot be configured with NSG

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I have provisioned App Gateway with WAF V2 SKU. Then, I have configured back-end pool to point to WebApp and added IP restrictions to allow only traffic from WAF IP.  Then, i am attempting to add NSG to the provisioned Subnet to further restrict traffic to the Frontend IP address.  I am getting an error (see below). Per [Application Gateway FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-faq#configuration) this should be possible, but having trouble. Here is are the details of the deployment error:

```
Network security group /subscriptions/49c19f96-135d-4599-ae34-fd9087ce2bf8/resourceGroups/dbt-sc-platform-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/BannerCIDRNsg blocks incoming internet traffic on ports 65200 - 65535 to subnet /subscriptions/49c19f96-135d-4599-ae34-fd9087ce2bf8/resourceGroups/dbt-sc-platform-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/dbt-sc-platform-rg/subnets/default, associated with Application Gateway /subscriptions/49c19f96-135d-4599-ae34-fd9087ce2bf8/resourceGroups/dbt-sc-platform-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/dbt-sc-appgw. This is not permitted for Application Gateways that have V2 Sku.
```

Comment: try using other sku? the error suggests v2 sku doesnt support it?

Comment: v1 sku did work, btw. I am trying to figure this out for v2 sku.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The error message displays that you need to add incoming internet traffic on ports **65200 - 65535** to subnet-default in your Network security group-BannerCIDRNsg.

[image]

Per [Application Gateway FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-faq#configuration), you can whitelist Application Gateway access to a few source IPs.

This scenario can be done using NSGs on Application Gateway subnet. The following restrictions should be put on the subnet in the listed order of priority:

> Allow incoming traffic from source IP/IP range.
>
> Exceptions must be put in for incoming traffic on ports **65503-65534**
>   for the Application Gateway V1 SKU and ports **65200 - 65535** for the V2
>   SKU. This port-range is required for Azure infrastructure
>   communication. They are protected (locked down) by Azure certificates.
>   Without proper certificates, external entities, including the
>   customers of those gateways, will not be able to initiate any changes
>   on those endpoints.
>
> Allow incoming Azure Load Balancer probes (AzureLoadBalancer tag) and
>   inbound virtual network traffic (VirtualNetwork tag) on the NSG.
>
> Block all other incoming traffic with a Deny all rule.
>
> Allow outbound traffic to the internet for all destinations.

Comment: Yes, I have read that FAQ article and the NSG that i was adding has the default rules.  I have rebuilt the set up using V1 version of the application gateway and it worked ok. My question is my V2 is giving me such error.

Comment: Re-edit my reply, there is a difference on ports 65503-65534 for the Application Gateway V1 SKU and ports 65200 - 65535 for the V2 SKU. Could you confirm that?

Comment: let me confirm that with my set up tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: I have tried to create a inbound rule to either allow "Internet" service tag or "Any" on ports 65200 - 65535 to Any/Any destination and I am still getting this error.

Comment: Any thoughts there?

Comment: @Roman Please check my update picture, you should add the port range as the destination in inbound NSG rule.

Answer (score 10):

I want to add on @Nancy's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52697957/1198379), that actually, as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/configuration-infrastructure#network-security-groups), there is no need to allow traffic from **`Any`** protocol. Allowing TCP traffic is enough.

There is also no need to allow traffic from **`Any`** source, it is sufficient to allow traffic from `GatewayManager` service tag.

> You must allow incoming Internet traffic on TCP ports 65503-65534 for
> the Application Gateway v1 SKU, and TCP ports 65200-65535 for the v2
> SKU with the destination subnet as Any and source as GatewayManager
> service tag. This port range is required for Azure infrastructure
> communication.

So, I created the security rule as follows:

[image: security rule on Azure]

It should also be noted that:

> These ports are protected (locked down) by Azure
> certificates. External entities, including the customers of those
> gateways, can't communicate on these endpoints.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks ccoutinho
I wuldve added the following as a comment but my reputations not high enough yet so..

Az CLI command for this:

```
az network nsg rule create -g <resourcegroup> --nsg-name <nsgname> -n GatewayManager --priority 4096 --source-port-range '*' --access allow --destination-port-ranges 65200-65535 --source-address-prefixes GatewayManager --protocol Tcp
```

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the error message "Subnet associated to gateway with v2 sku" when trying to associate a subnet containing a Gateway V2 WAF to an existing NSG.

Strangely though it was no problem navigating to the VNET -> SubNet and after clicking the given SubNet then associating the NSG to that SubNet.

Comment: Did you delete the security rule that allow incoming internet traffic on ports 65200 - 65535, as described in the accepted answer? I guess not :)

Answer (score 0):

To associate NSG to the subnet containing an application gateway, allow traffic from

1. source: 'GatewayManager', port: Any to Destination: 'GatewayManager' service tag, Destination port: 65503-65534
2. Traffic from the AzureLoadBalancer tag with the destination subnet as Any must be allowed.
   Note: just be cautious that you don't add deny rule before these inbound rules, so give them a low priority no, to avoid accidental misconfiguration

Also,

1. Outbound Internet connectivity can't be blocked

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/configuration-infrastructure#network-security-groups